# Series. Uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$ vs. any interval $[-K,K]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

As the title indicates I am slightly unsure about a setup used for convergence of a series.

I was wondering if there is/what the difference is between showing that a series is uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$ vs. uniformly convergent in any interval $[-K,K]$, for fixed $K$ where $0<K<\infty$.

If I want to show that the sum function is continuous in any $x$ in the real numbers I would just choose $K=\text{numerical($x$)}$ and obtain continuity on $[-x,x]$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your series is made up of terms which are continuous.
The sum function being continuous is only a necessary condition for uniform convergence. It is not sufficient. The series $\sum \frac  x {n^{2}}$ is uniformly convergent on $[-K,K]$ for any $K >0$ (by M-test) but it is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$ because the general term $\frac x {n^{2}}$ does not tend to $0$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$.  The sum is $\frac {\pi^{2}} 6 x$ which is continuous on the whole line but still the series is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: I think I get it. But could I argue that the sum must be convergent on the whole real axis since it is made up of terms which are continuous along with the fact that the series is uniformly convergent on [−K,K]  for any K>0?

Comment: No that is an invalid argument. Continuity of the sum does not yield uniform convergence . Be clear as to what theorem you are applying. @Jacob

Comment: I meant it the other way around. I am unsure if it has a name but in my book I have a theorem that states if the terms of the series are continuous functions and the series is uniformly convergent then it implies the sum is continuous.

Comment: @Jacob It is true that if the series converges uniformly on $[-K,K]$ for each $K$ then the sum function is continuous on the whole real line. But your question is whether uniform convergence on $[-K,K]$ for each $K$ implies uniform convergence on t he whole line and this is false.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't even realize the difference when writing the question. The distinction is clear now. Thank you very much for being patient.